# how to avoid scrolling of table when on focus of selectize dropdown

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I am using selectize drop down in an html table, where in last few columns of the table has drop down.

when i try to edit the value in the drop down it automatically brings the control to beginning of the table. i.e when i click on a particular row on selectize drop down it takes me all the way back to the starting column of the table.

my table has 30+ columns and not able to edit the values because of this issue.

While adding values to the empty field its working fine. problem is only when i try to edit the existing value.

when i click on Markdown drop down it will automatically brings the control of scroll to beginning of the table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Selectize provides an input field that positions absolute.we need to change the positioning using the css.

```
.select-dropdown-auto{ 
         position: relative; 
         .selectize-input{ 
                input{ 
                    position: relative !important; left: 0px !important; 
                 } 
          } 
   }
```